# How to build gem5 on Ubuntu 17.10 with GCC 7.2, dealing with issues in C++ compilation?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, scons, gem5

I am having lots of issues with building gem5 as directed in the official documentation.

These are the commands I have used:

```
git clone https://gem5.googlesource.com/public/gem5
cd gem5
python2 `which scons` build/MIPS/gem5.opt
```

Which results in this output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Warning: Your compiler doesn't support incremental linking and lto at the same time, so lto is being disabled. To force lto on anyway, use the --force-lto option. That will disable partial linking.
Checking for C header file Python.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library python2.7... (cached) yes
Checking for C library pthread... (cached) yes
Checking for C library dl... (cached) yes
Checking for C library util... (cached) yes
Checking for C library m... (cached) yes
Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... (cached) yes
Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... (cached) yes
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... (cached) yes
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library None... (cached) no
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library rt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library tcmalloc... (cached) yes
Checking for backtrace_symbols_fd((void*)0, 0, 0) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file fenv.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file png.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/if_tun.h... (cached) yes
Checking size of struct kvm_xsave ... (cached) yes
Checking for member exclude_host in struct perf_event_attr...(cached) yes
Checking whether __i386__ is declared... (cached) no
Checking whether __x86_64__ is declared... (cached) yes
Building in /home/j/gem5/build/MIPS
Using saved variables file /home/j/gem5/build/variables/MIPS
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
 [     CXX] MIPS/dev/serial/serial.cc -> .o
In file included from build/MIPS/sim/sim_object.hh:57:0,
                 from build/MIPS/dev/serial/serial.hh:44,
                 from build/MIPS/dev/serial/serial.cc:40:
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:806:12: error: 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
       std::function<void(void)> callback;
            ^~~~~~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:810:37: error: 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
     EventFunctionWrapper(const std::function<void(void)> &callback,
                                     ^~~~~~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:810:45: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
     EventFunctionWrapper(const std::function<void(void)> &callback,
                                             ^
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh: In constructor 'EventFunctionWrapper::EventFunctionWrapper(int)':
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:814:17: error: 'p' was not declared in this scope
         : Event(p), callback(callback), _name(name)
                 ^
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:814:21: error: class 'EventFunctionWrapper' does not have any field named 'callback'
         : Event(p), callback(callback), _name(name)
                     ^~~~~~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:814:30: error: 'callback' was not declared in this scope
         : Event(p), callback(callback), _name(name)
                              ^~~~~~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:814:30: note: suggested alternative: 'Callback'
         : Event(p), callback(callback), _name(name)
                              ^~~~~~~~
                              Callback
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:814:51: error: invalid use of non-static member function 'virtual const string EventFunctionWrapper::name() const'
         : Event(p), callback(callback), _name(name)
                                                   ^
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:823:5: note: declared here
     name() const
     ^~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:816:13: error: 'del' was not declared in this scope
         if (del)
             ^~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh: In member function 'virtual void EventFunctionWrapper::process()':
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:820:22: error: 'callback' was not declared in this scope
     void process() { callback(); }
                      ^~~~~~~~
build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh:820:22: note: suggested alternative: 'Callback'
     void process() { callback(); }
                      ^~~~~~~~
                      Callback
scons: *** [build/MIPS/dev/serial/serial.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

gcc & g++ versions:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0
```

Hardware:

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 x86_64
Host: XPS 15 9560
Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic
CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile
GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics
Memory: 4688MiB / 15771MiB
GPU: Intel Integrated Memory: 4688MiB / 15771MiB
```

I tried adding

```
#include <functional>
```

to ~/gem5/build/MIPS/sim/eventq.hh after reading that gcc7 is a lot less lenient on headers than previous versions, but I am unsure if this helps as it just creates a different issue:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Warning: Your compiler doesn't support incremental linking and lto at the same time, so lto is being disabled. To force lto on anyway, use the --force-lto option. That will disable partial linking.
Checking for C header file Python.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C library python2.7... (cached) yes
Checking for C library pthread... (cached) yes
Checking for C library dl... (cached) yes
Checking for C library util... (cached) yes
Checking for C library m... (cached) yes
Checking for accept(0,0,0) in C++ library None... (cached) yes
Checking for zlibVersion() in C++ library z... (cached) yes
Checking for GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION in C++ library protobuf... (cached) yes
Checking for clock_nanosleep(0,0,NULL,NULL) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library None... (cached) no
Checking for timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, NULL, NULL) in C library rt... (cached) yes
Checking for C library tcmalloc... (cached) yes
Checking for backtrace_symbols_fd((void*)0, 0, 0) in C library None... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file fenv.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file png.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/kvm.h... (cached) yes
Checking for C header file linux/if_tun.h... (cached) yes
Checking size of struct kvm_xsave ... (cached) yes
Checking for member exclude_host in struct perf_event_attr...(cached) yes
Checking whether __i386__ is declared... (cached) no
Checking whether __x86_64__ is declared... (cached) yes
Building in /home/j/gem5/build/MIPS
Using saved variables file /home/j/gem5/build/variables/MIPS
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
 [     CXX] MIPS/dev/serial/serial.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Terminal.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/TerminalVerbose.hh
 [SO PARAM] Platform -> MIPS/params/Platform.hh
 [SO PARAM] Terminal -> MIPS/params/Terminal.hh
 [SO PARAM] Uart -> MIPS/params/Uart.hh
 [SO PARAM] IntrControl -> MIPS/params/IntrControl.hh
 [SO PARAM] BasicPioDevice -> MIPS/params/BasicPioDevice.hh
 [SO PARAM] PioDevice -> MIPS/params/PioDevice.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/isa_traits.hh
 [ CFG ISA]  -> MIPS/config/the_isa.hh
 [ENUMDECL] MemoryMode -> MIPS/enums/MemoryMode.hh
 [SO PARAM] System -> MIPS/params/System.hh
 [SO PARAM] MemObject -> MIPS/params/MemObject.hh
 [ENUMDECL] PwrState -> MIPS/enums/PwrState.hh
 [SO PARAM] ClockedObject -> MIPS/params/ClockedObject.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/registers.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/types.hh
 [SO PARAM] ClockDomain -> MIPS/params/ClockDomain.hh
 [SO PARAM] DerivedClockDomain -> MIPS/params/DerivedClockDomain.hh
 [SO PARAM] SrcClockDomain -> MIPS/params/SrcClockDomain.hh
 [SO PARAM] AbstractMemory -> MIPS/params/AbstractMemory.hh
 [SO PARAM] ThermalModel -> MIPS/params/ThermalModel.hh
 [SO PARAM] PowerModel -> MIPS/params/PowerModel.hh
 [SO PARAM] VoltageDomain -> MIPS/params/VoltageDomain.hh
 [ISA DESC] MIPS/arch/mips/isa/main.isa -> generated/decoder-g.cc.inc, generated/decoder-ns.cc.inc, generated/decode-method.cc.inc, generated/decoder.hh, generated/decoder-g.hh.inc, generated/decoder-ns.hh.inc, generated/exec-g.cc.inc, generated/exec-ns.cc.inc, generated/max_inst_regs.hh, generated/decoder.cc, generated/inst-constrs.cc, generated/generic_cpu_exec.cc
 [SO PARAM] PowerModelState -> MIPS/params/PowerModelState.hh
 [SO PARAM] SubSystem -> MIPS/params/SubSystem.hh
 [SO PARAM] ThermalDomain -> MIPS/params/ThermalDomain.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/dev/serial/terminal.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/dev/serial/uart.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Uart.hh
 [SO PARAM] Uart8250 -> MIPS/params/Uart8250.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/dev/serial/uart8250.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> MIPS/dev/serial/lib.o.partial
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/decoder.hh
 [ENUMDECL] StaticInstFlags -> MIPS/enums/StaticInstFlags.hh
 [ENUMDECL] OpClass -> MIPS/enums/OpClass.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/arch/generic/decode_cache.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/arch/generic/mmapped_ipr.cc -> .o
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/tlb.hh
 [SO PARAM] MipsTLB -> MIPS/params/MipsTLB.hh
 [SO PARAM] BaseTLB -> MIPS/params/BaseTLB.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/arch/generic/tlb.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/arch/generic/pseudo_inst.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> MIPS/arch/generic/lib.o.partial
 [   SLICC] src/mem/protocol/MI_example.slicc -> MIPS/mem/protocol/AccessPermission.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/AccessPermission.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/AccessType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/AccessType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/CacheRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/CacheRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/CacheResourceType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/CacheResourceType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/CoherenceRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/CoherenceRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/CoherenceResponseType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/CoherenceResponseType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMARequestMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMARequestMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMARequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMARequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMAResponseMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMAResponseMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMAResponseType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMAResponseType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMASequencerRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMASequencerRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Controller.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Controller.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Controller.py, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Event.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Event.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_State.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_State.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_TBE.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_TBE.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Transitions.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DMA_Wakeup.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DirectoryRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/DirectoryRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Controller.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Controller.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Controller.py, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Entry.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Entry.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Event.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Event.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_State.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_State.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_TBE.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_TBE.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Transitions.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/Directory_Wakeup.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/HSAScope.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/HSAScope.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/HSASegment.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/HSASegment.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/InvalidateGeneratorStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/InvalidateGeneratorStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Controller.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Controller.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Controller.py, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Entry.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Entry.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Event.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Event.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_State.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_State.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_TBE.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_TBE.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Transitions.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/L1Cache_Wakeup.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/LinkDirection.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/LinkDirection.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/LockStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/LockStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MachineType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MachineType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorIndex.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorIndex.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorTraining.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorTraining.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MaskPredictorType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryControlRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryControlRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MemoryRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/MessageSizeType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/MessageSizeType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/PrefetchBit.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/PrefetchBit.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/RequestMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/RequestMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/RequestStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/RequestStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/ResponseMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/ResponseMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/RubyAccessMode.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/RubyAccessMode.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/RubyRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/RubyRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerMsg.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerMsg.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerRequestType.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerRequestType.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/SequencerStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/SeriesRequestGeneratorStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/SeriesRequestGeneratorStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/TesterStatus.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/TesterStatus.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/TransitionResult.cc, MIPS/mem/protocol/TransitionResult.hh, MIPS/mem/protocol/Types.hh
MI_example-cache.sm:179: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-cache.sm:181: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-cache.sm:336: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-cache.sm:350: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Scalar'
MI_example-cache.sm:354: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Scalar'
MI_example-dir.sm:183: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'bool'
MI_example-dir.sm:398: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:402: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:482: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dir.sm:277: Warning: Unused action: a_sendWriteBackAck, Send writeback ack to requestor
MI_example-dma.sm:189: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
MI_example-dma.sm:193: Warning: Non-void return ignored, return type is 'Tick'
 [     CXX] MIPS/mem/ruby/profiler/AccessTraceForAddress.cc -> .o
 [MAKE INC] MIPS/mem/ruby/slicc_interface/Message.hh -> protocol/Message.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubySystem -> MIPS/params/RubySystem.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubyController -> MIPS/params/RubyController.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/RubyQueue.hh
 [SO PARAM] MessageBuffer -> MIPS/params/MessageBuffer.hh
 [SO PARAM] SimpleMemory -> MIPS/params/SimpleMemory.hh
 [MAKE INC] MIPS/mem/ruby/slicc_interface/RubyRequest.hh -> protocol/RubyRequest.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/mem/ruby/profiler/AddressProfiler.cc -> .o
 [SO PARAM] RubyNetwork -> MIPS/params/RubyNetwork.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubySequencer -> MIPS/params/RubySequencer.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubyCache -> MIPS/params/RubyCache.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubyPort -> MIPS/params/RubyPort.hh
 [SO PARAM] BasicExtLink -> MIPS/params/BasicExtLink.hh
 [SO PARAM] BasicIntLink -> MIPS/params/BasicIntLink.hh
 [SO PARAM] BasicLink -> MIPS/params/BasicLink.hh
 [SO PARAM] ReplacementPolicy -> MIPS/params/ReplacementPolicy.hh
 [SO PARAM] BasicRouter -> MIPS/params/BasicRouter.hh
 [SO PARAM] RubyDirectoryMemory -> MIPS/params/RubyDirectoryMemory.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/mem/ruby/profiler/Profiler.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/mem/ruby/profiler/StoreTrace.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> MIPS/mem/ruby/profiler/lib.o.partial
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/utility.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Branch.hh
 [SO PARAM] BranchPredictor -> MIPS/params/BranchPredictor.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/bpred_unit.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Fetch.hh
 [SO PARAM] LocalBP -> MIPS/params/LocalBP.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/2bit_local.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/btb.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Indirect.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/indirect.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/ras.cc -> .o
 [SO PARAM] TournamentBP -> MIPS/params/TournamentBP.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/tournament.cc -> .o
 [SO PARAM] BiModeBP -> MIPS/params/BiModeBP.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/bi_mode.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/LTage.hh
 [SO PARAM] LTAGE -> MIPS/params/LTAGE.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/pred/ltage.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> MIPS/cpu/pred/lib.o.partial
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/TraceCPUData.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/TraceCPUInst.hh
 [SO PARAM] TraceCPU -> MIPS/params/TraceCPU.hh
 [  PROTOC] MIPS/proto/inst_dep_record.proto -> MIPS/proto/inst_dep_record.pb.cc, MIPS/proto/inst_dep_record.pb.h
 [  PROTOC] MIPS/proto/packet.proto -> MIPS/proto/packet.pb.cc, MIPS/proto/packet.pb.h
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/interrupts.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/microcode_rom.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Mwait.hh
 [SO PARAM] BaseCPU -> MIPS/params/BaseCPU.hh
 [SO PARAM] MipsInterrupts -> MIPS/params/MipsInterrupts.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/MipsPRA.hh
 [SO PARAM] InstTracer -> MIPS/params/InstTracer.hh
 [SO PARAM] MipsISA -> MIPS/params/MipsISA.hh
 [SO PARAM] Process -> MIPS/params/Process.hh
 [SO PARAM] EmulatedDriver -> MIPS/params/EmulatedDriver.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/cpu/trace/trace_cpu.cc -> .o
 [    LINK]  -> MIPS/cpu/trace/lib.o.partial
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/arguments.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/async.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/backtrace_glibc.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/core.cc -> .o
 [VER TAGS]  -> MIPS/sim/tags.cc
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/tags.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/cxx_config.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/CxxConfig.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/cxx_manager.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/cxx_config_ini.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/debug.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/py_interact.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Checkpoint.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/eventq.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/global_event.cc -> .o
 [CONFIG H] HAVE_PROTOBUF, 1 -> MIPS/config/have_protobuf.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/init.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/init_signals.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/TimeSync.hh
 [SO PARAM] Root -> MIPS/params/Root.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/root.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/serialize.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Drain.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/drain.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/sim_events.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/sim_object.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/sub_system.cc -> .o
 [SO PARAM] TickedObject -> MIPS/params/TickedObject.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/ticked_object.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/simulate.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/stat_control.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/stat_register.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/ClockDomain.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/clock_domain.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/VoltageDomain.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/voltage_domain.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/se_signal.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/linear_solver.cc -> .o
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/remote_gdb.hh
 [CONFIG H] USE_KVM, 0 -> MIPS/config/use_kvm.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Loader.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/WorkItems.hh
 [CONFIG H] HAVE_PERF_ATTR_EXCLUDE_HOST, 1 -> MIPS/config/have_perf_attr_exclude_host.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/isa.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/CCRegs.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/FloatRegs.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/IntRegs.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/VecRegs.hh
 [GENERATE] mips -> MIPS/arch/stacktrace.hh
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Stack.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/system.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/DVFS.hh
 [SO PARAM] DVFSHandler -> MIPS/params/DVFSHandler.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/dvfs_handler.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/clocked_object.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/mathexpr.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/aux_vector.cc -> .o
 [ TRACING]  -> MIPS/debug/Fault.hh
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/faults.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/process.cc -> .o
 [     CXX] MIPS/sim/fd_array.cc -> .o
build/MIPS/sim/fd_array.cc: In member function 'void FDArray::restoreFileOffsets()':
build/MIPS/sim/fd_array.cc:139:5: internal compiler error: in assign_temp, at function.c:968
     };
     ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
scons: *** [build/MIPS/sim/fd_array.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I have also attempted using gcc-6 insead of the ubuntu 17.10 default of 7.2, and received complaints that scrons does not trust anything but default gcc and clang.

Answer (score 1):

This was raised on the mailing list today: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15116.html

One workaround that does not require modifying the code is:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-6 gcc-6
CC=gcc-6 CXX=g++-6 scons
```

Also:

- there is already a related fix at: https://github.com/gem5/gem5/commit/5c41076bd7610d03431fd0dd89bd0fdc7f30d6bd
- there is a pending patch that tries to fix some further errors: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/8541